# How to use DOMDocument loadHtml to load the exact input values

Tags: php, domdocument

I am using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to load and process text as an HTML.

I noticed that as soon as I load the input string using loadHtml(value) method, it adds several tags like `<html><body>` etc.

There are couple of problems :
(1) If you load a text using loadHTML(value), then it automatically adds closing tags. Is there any way to avoid it ? **How to prevent DOMDocument from adding closing tags?**

e.g.

```
$value = "Hi there ! <my-custom-tag>";
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
// Load HTML
$doc->loadHTML($value);
error_log(" value after loading in html dom - ". $doc->saveHTML());
```

Output: The last statement error_log prints as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>Hi there ! <my-custom-tag></my-custom-tag></p></body></html>
```

(2) When I use loadHTML method to load text with a bracketed URL like ‹http://stackoverflow.com › , it just strips out the strings after //.
**How to make DOMDocument preserve such custom tags with Url ?**

e.g.

```
$value = "Hi there ! <http://something.com>";
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
// Load HTML
$doc->loadHTML($value);
error_log(" value after loading in html dom - ". $doc->saveHTML());
```

Output: The last statement error_log prints as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>Hi there ! <http:></http:></p></body></html>
```

Comment: As its name implies, 'loadHTML' expects to get HTML. If you can't give it HTML, you'll need to find some other method to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use DOM?

If you supply html and need to use DOM, you can get your tag by doing:

```
    $doc->getElementsByTagName('my-custom-tag');
```

but if it's a string, it makes more sense to use regex operators like

```
    $str = 'Hello <my-tag>info</my-tag>';

    preg_match("'<my-tag>(.*?)</my-tag>'si", $str, $match);

    echo $match[1];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use DOM. What I am trying to understand is (1) Why DOM force the closing tag on the input HTML tags, is there a way to stop that in constructor? At least I could not find a way so far. (2) Why can't it accept the complete URL as a Tag <'http:/xxxx.com'> ? It is stripping out xxxx.com from the tag and then gives you <http:></http:>.